# Why are all elements stringified when I apply to data.frames containing strings?

Tags: r

When calling `apply` on a data.frame containing strings, all other elements seem to be coerced to strings before being passed to the supplied function:

```
> x<-data.frame(a=1:3,b=6:8)
> apply(x,1,function(y){y["b"]})
[1] 6 7 8
> x<-data.frame(a=1:3,b=6:8,d=c("a","bc","def"))
> apply(x,1,function(y){y["b"]})
[1] "6" "7" "8"
>
```

Why is this happening? How can I avoid it?

Answer (score 5):

The reason that this occurs is that the `apply` function coerces your data.frame into a matrix and then performs the operation. If you look at the code for `apply` you'll find:

```
if (is.object(X)) 
    X <- if (dl == 2L) 
        as.matrix(X)
    else as.array(X)
```

Matrices can only hold one data type and when there are multiple, it coerces to the highest level one. In your case, character. So what can you do instead? Use the `aaply` from `plyr`.
Running your code with a slight modification (using `[[` instead of `[` so it returns a vector rather than a data frame):

```
x<-data.frame(a=1:3,b=6:8,d=c("a","bc","def"))
library(plyr)
aaply(x, 1, function(y){y[["b"]]}, .expand=FALSE)

1 2 3 
6 7 8
```

Comment: Note you don't really need the anonymous function ``aaply(x, 1, `[[`, 'b', .expand=FALSE)`` would work well.

Answer (score 0):

one solution is to convert y to a data.frame

```
apply(x,1,function(y){as.data.frame(y)[2,]})
```

[1] 6 7 8

Comment: @TimN I use as.data.frame because in this case the class of y is a data.frame.with POSIXct, what will be the class of y?